# chai always gives me a stack trace when a test fails. Even when I say chai.config.includeStack = false

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Whatever I do, I always get a stack trace when a chai test fails.  I am using chai.config.includeStack = false, as you can see in the following jsfiddle.  I have tried chai.Assertion.includeStack = false, also.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhedin/2kk09jka/6/

```
mocha.setup('bdd');
chai.should();
chai.config.includeStack = false;

describe('"slow tests" of the ACPU', function () {
    var expect = chai.expect;
    chai.config.includeStack = false;
    chai.Assertion.includeStack = false;

    it('should say that true is true when I just say so', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(false);
    });

});

mocha.run();
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Chai won't turn the whole stack on or off if you perform equality tests. However, if you check for falsehood, you can turn the whole stack off. Try this code:

```
mocha.setup('bdd');

var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;
chai.should();

describe('includeStack false', function () {
    before(function () {
        chai.config.includeStack = false;
    });

    it('expect equal', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(false);
    });

    it('assert equal', function () {
        assert.equal(true, false);
    });

    it('should equal', function () {
        true.should.equal(false);
    });

    it('expect', function () {
        expect(true).to.be.false;
    });

    it('assert', function () {
        assert.isFalse(true);
    });

    it('should', function () {
        true.should.be.false;
    });

});

mocha.run();
```

The first 3 tests will have a stack trace. The last 3 tests won't have a stack trace. I could not find documentation or an issue report that explains why it is this way.

Comment: Thanks, Louis.  I suppose if I get ambitious I can look at the code and see how the two cases are handled differently.  I wonder whether I should submit this to the chai project as a bug. ?